# position small element below title but maintaining the vertically alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the layout with the code below, where each list item has a title "Item 0", below there is a small tag with text "Description Item 0" and then two select menus at right. I want the layout as it is, the only issue is that I want the small tag "Description Item 0" below the title "Item 0" but its not working. Do you know how to put the small tag below the title "Item 0" and maitain the vertically alignment of elements?

example:https://jsfiddle.net/ccwag5ks/

HTML code:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <span>Item 0</span>
              <span>Description Item 0</span>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div
```

>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use put the two items in the same `<span>` and use a `<br />` ?

`<span>Item 0<br />Description Item 0</span>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span>Item 0<br />Description Item 0</span>
            
            <form>
            <select class="custom-select form-control">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>
            </form>

            <form>
            <select class="custom-select form-control">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>
            </form>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```